# Capture both stdout and stderr in Bash

Tags: bash, stream, pipe, stdout, stderr

I know this syntax

```
var=`myscript.sh`
```

or

```
var=$(myscript.sh)
```

Will capture the result (`stdout`) of `myscript.sh` into `var`. I could redirect `stderr` into `stdout` if I wanted to capture both.  How to save each of them to separate variables?

My use case here is if the return code is nonzero I want to echo `stderr` and suppress otherwise.  There may be other ways to do this but this approach seems it will work, if it's actually possible.

Comment: ah , there is no way to capture both without temp file, see my answer here which show how to get stderr and pass stdout to the screen (in case of dialog):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13427218/815386

Comment: here is additional info http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002
`What you cannot do is capture stdout in one variable, and stderr in another, using only FD redirections. You must use a temporary file (or a named pipe) to achieve that one.`

Comment: is there some specific reason why you don't want to use temp files? Using temp files is very much idiomatic within a bash programming environment

Comment: Related (and having a pretty easy solution): [Bash script - store stderr in variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3130375/2533433)

Comment: @eicto Yes, there is a way, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28796214/2350426).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no way to capture both without temp file.

You can capture stderr to variable and pass stdout to user screen (sample from [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)):

```
exec 3>&1                    # Save the place that stdout (1) points to.
output=$(command 2>&1 1>&3)  # Run command.  stderr is captured.
exec 3>&-                    # Close FD #3.

# Or this alternative, which captures stderr, letting stdout through:
{ output=$(command 2>&1 1>&3-) ;} 3>&1
```

But there is no way to capture both stdout and stderr:

> *What you cannot do is capture stdout in one variable, and stderr in another, using only FD redirections. You **must** use a temporary file (or a named pipe) to achieve that one.*

Comment: Thanks - accepting this answer because using file descriptors 3 and above avoids using "temp files" per what I intended to mean by temp files (even if technically, literally, a temp file).

Comment: Thank you. Based on this answer I'm using fd 3 to send extra information between two scripts, and capturing it from the calling script using `{ output=$(command 3>&1 1>&4-) ;} 4>&1`

Comment: I object!  There is a way to capture both, stdout and stderr.  [You can capture stdout into one and stderr into another variable with only FD redirections.  No need to use some temporary file or named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41069638/490291).  The only downside is that it's a bit ugly, though.

Answer (score 68):

There's a really ugly way to capture `stderr` and `stdout` in two separate variables without temporary files (if you like plumbing), using [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), `source`, and `declare` appropriately. I'll call your command `banana`. You can mimic such a command with a function:

```
banana() {
    echo "banana to stdout"
    echo >&2 "banana to stderr"
}
```

I'll assume you want standard output of `banana` in variable `bout` and standard error of `banana` in variable `berr`. Here's the magic that'll achieve that (Bash≥4 only):

```
. <({ berr=$({ bout=$(banana); } 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)
```

---

So, what's happening here?

Let's start from the innermost term:

```
bout=$(banana)
```

This is just the standard way to assign to `bout` the standard output of `banana`, the standard error being displayed on your terminal.

Then:

```
{ bout=$(banana); } 2>&1
```

will still assign to `bout` the stdout of `banana`, but the stderr of `banana` is displayed on terminal via stdout (thanks to the redirection `2>&1`.

Then:

```
{ bout=$(banana); } 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2
```

will do as above, but will also display on the terminal (via stderr) the content of `bout` with the `declare` builtin: this will be reused soon.

Then:

```
berr=$({ bout=$(banana); } 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2); declare -p berr
```

will assign to `berr` the stderr of `banana` and display the content of `berr` with `declare`.

At this point, you'll have on your terminal screen:

```
declare -- bout="banana to stdout"
declare -- berr="banana to stderr"
```

with the line

```
declare -- bout="banana to stdout"
```

being displayed via stderr.

A final redirection:

```
{ berr=$({ bout=$(banana); } 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1
```

will have the previous displayed via stdout.

Finally, we use a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to *source* the content of these lines.

---

You mentioned the return code of the command too. Change `banana` to:

```
banana() {
    echo "banana to stdout"
    echo >&2 "banana to stderr"
    return 42
}
```

We'll also have the return code of `banana` in the variable `bret` like so:

```
. <({ berr=$({ bout=$(banana); bret=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p bout bret >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)
```

---

You can do without sourcing and a process substitution by using `eval` too (and it works with Bash<4 too):

```
eval "$({ berr=$({ bout=$(banana); bret=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p bout bret >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)"
```

And all this is safe, because the only stuff we're `source`ing or `eval`ing are obtained from `declare -p` and will always be properly escaped.

---

Of course, if you want the output in an array (e.g., with `mapfile`, if you're using Bash≥4—otherwise replace `mapfile` with a `while`–`read` loop), the adaptation is straightforward.

For example:

```
banana() {
    printf 'banana to stdout %d\n' {1..10}
    echo >&2 'banana to stderr'
    return 42
}

. <({ berr=$({ mapfile -t bout < <(banana); } 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)
```

and with return code:

```
. <({ berr=$({ mapfile -t bout< <(banana; bret=$?; declare -p bret >&3); } 3>&2 2>&1; declare -p bout >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)
```

Comment: Awesome answer — this is so powerful!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I am able to use your `eval` example and replicate the same `banana` output. Next, I tried to pass in a command via variable and have it working with `ls "foo"` but am having issues with `ls "foo bar"` -- note the space in the quoted string. In the latter case, I am seeing the following error captured in berr: `ls: cannot access "foo: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access bar": No such file or directory` This leads me to believe the quoting around the file path is not sufficient to escape the space. Can you think of a solution for this? BTW setting `IFS=''` did not work.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf The article [Bash: Preserving Whitespace Using set and eval](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-preserving-whitespace-using-set-and-eval) has me wondering if whitespace preservation with eval is the root issue. I am not certain I understand the issue well enough at this point to determine how to resolve it yet.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf My sensibilities say to stay away from `eval` if at all possible but the `. <({...` example seemed to not work so I was trying to make the `eval` version work for my present needs. A bit more background: I am running this a computer that has bash version 3.1.21.

Comment: @JohnMarkMitchell: it works fine for me (even on 3.1): `eval "$({ berr=$({ bout=$(ls "foo bar"); bret=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p bout bret >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)"; declare -p bout berr`. I get: `declare -- berr="ls: cannot access foo bar: No such file or directory"` as wanted.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Try setting a variable e.g. `command='ls "foo bar"'` then pass that to your masterful one liner as variable. That is the scenario that the problem happens.

Comment: @JohnMarkMitchell You're using an antipattern here! [Don't put commands into variables!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I appreciate your patience here. I have learned much from you and your informative remarks. Can you test the dot operator version of your script and see if you are getting the full return results from the %d {1..10} version of banana? I am only seeing "banana to stdout 1" or was that a known limitation? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JohnMarkMitchell: In the last example I use `mapfile` to get the output lines in an _array_. To get the array `bout` printed on scren, don't use `echo "$bout"` (this only prints the first field of the array). I usually use `declare` to inspect the content of a variable: `declare -p bout` should show the correct content.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I greatly appreciate all your help. As it turns out, some of the troubles I was having sourced from one of the target systems I was needed to run my script on having a version of `bash` < 4. This means the `mapfile` command had not been introduced yet and the `source` (`.`) version of your solution fails silently. As a result, I am back to using the `eval` version. I share this in hopes of sparing others the same troubles if they know their script might be run where the `bash` version is < 4. Gniourf, you might want to add the `bash` version dependency on your solution above.

Comment: so you basically generate source code dynamically! [ingenious](https://gist.github.com/AquariusPower/ee2b7fc44e674296a324)! thx vm!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I munched your answer - somewhat - into an easy to use [bash recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41069638/490291)

Answer (score 21):

You can do:

```
OUT=$(myscript.sh 2> errFile)
ERR=$(<errFile)
```

Now `$OUT` will have standard output of your script and `$ERR` has error output of your script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify without temp files.

Answer (score 8):

An easy, but not elegant way:  Redirect stderr to a temporary file and then read it back:

```
TMP=$(mktemp)
var=$(myscript.sh 2> "$TMP")
err=$(cat "$TMP")
rm "$TMP"
```

Answer (score 7):

While I have not found a way to capture stderr and stdout to separate variables in bash, I send both to the same variable with…

```
result=$( { grep "JUNK" ./junk.txt; } 2>&1 )
```

…  then I check the exit status “$?”, and act appropriately on the data in $result.

Answer (score -1):

```
# NAME
#   capture - capture the stdout and stderr output of a command
# SYNOPSIS
#   capture <result> <error> <command>
# DESCRIPTION
#   This shell function captures the stdout and stderr output of <command> in
#   the shell variables <result> and <error>.
# ARGUMENTS
#   <result>  - the name of the shell variable to capture stdout
#   <error>   - the name of the shell variable to capture stderr
#   <command> - the command to execute
# ENVIRONMENT
#   The following variables are mdified in the caller's context:
#    - <result>
#    - <error>
# RESULT
#   Retuns the exit code of <command>.
# SOURCE
capture ()
{
    # Name of shell variable to capture the stdout of command.
    result=$1
    shift

    # Name of shell variable to capture the stderr of command.
    error=$1
    shift

    # Local AWK program to extract the error, the result, and the exit code
    # parts of the captured output of command.
    local evaloutput='
        {
            output [NR] = $0
        }
        END \
        {
            firstresultline = NR - output [NR - 1] - 1
            if (Var == "error") \
            {
                for (i = 1; i < firstresultline; ++ i)
                {
                    printf ("%s\n", output [i])
                }
            }
            else if (Var == "result") \
            {
                for (i = firstresultline; i < NR - 1; ++ i)
                {
                    printf ("%s\n", output [i])
                }
            }
            else \
            {
                printf ("%d", output [NR])
            }
        }'

    # Capture the stderr and stdout output of command, as well as its exit code.
    local output="$(
    {
        local stdout
        stdout="$($*)"
        local exitcode=$?
        printf "\n%s\n%d\n%d\n" \
               "$stdout" "$(echo "$stdout" | wc -l)" "$exitcode"
    } 2>&1)"

    # extract the stderr, the stdout, and the exit code parts of the captured
    # output of command.
    printf -v $error "%s" \
                     "$(echo "$output" | gawk -v Var="error" "$evaloutput")"
    printf -v $result "%s" \
                      "$(echo "$output" | gawk -v Var="result" "$evaloutput")"
    return $(echo "$output" | gawk "$evaloutput")
}
```

Comment: This is wrong: the assignment `result=$(command)` is run in a subshell: everything inside the parentheses in `error=$( ... )` is in a subshell; hence `result` will never be seen. You can try it yourself: `c() { echo >&2 'to stderr'; echo 'to stdout'; }; error=$( { result=$(c); } 2>&1); echo "result: $result"; echo "error: $error"`. You'll see that `result` is empty. See my answer for a method that actually works.