# Setting a variable within command substitution

Tags: bash, curl, command-substitution

I'm trying to [get both the HTTP code and the output of a `curl` command](https://superuser.com/a/862395/367539) as part of a shell script, but in turn I'm trying to set both of them as variables. My code (which uses the [pushbullet API](https://docs.pushbullet.com/#pushes)) looks like this:

```
CURL_OUTPUT="$(exec 3>&1; \
  HTTP_CODE="$(curl -s -S \
    -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$ACCT_TOKEN" \
    -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary "$JSON")" \
)"
```

which should theoretically set `$CURL_OUTPUT` to the JSON returned by `curl` and `$HTTP_CODE` to the status code I get. Instead, I get only `$CURL_OUTPUT`; `$HTTP_CODE` is empty.

However, if I don't do the outer nest, like so:

```
exec 3>&1; \
  HTTP_CODE="$(curl -s -S \
    -w "%{http_code}" -o >(cat >&3) \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$ACCT_TOKEN" \
    -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-binary "$JSON")" \
```

The command works as expected; I get the JSON redirected to stdout, and the status code ends up in `$HTTP_CODE`.

So is it possible to get both outputs? Can I assign variables within a command substitution line?

Comment: Each `$()` is a sub-shell, so no, you can't assign inside one and view it outside.

Comment: If that's the case, then [going by this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806626/capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash) my only options are a temporary file or a named pipe?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes.

Comment: @RogerFilmyer: Out of curiosity, isn't it possible to just output both the body and the -w message to stdout, so they can be captured, and then separate them afterwards?