# Why does this bash command's return value change?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

### What I actually want to do

Save a command's output and check its return status.

### The solution?

After some googling I found basically the same answer here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921658/save-command-output-on-variable-and-check-exit-status) as well as on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/29596/478654) and [Unix/Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192298/only-pipe-on-success):

```sh
if output=$(command); then
  echo "success: $output"
fi
```

### Problem

When trying out this solution with `command info put` the if clause is executed even if the actual command fails, but I can't explain myself why?

I tried to check the return value `$?` manually and it seems like the `var=` changes the return value:

```sh
$ info put
info: No menu item 'put' in node '(dir)Top'
$ echo $?
1

$ command info put
info: No menu item 'put' in node '(dir)Top'
$ echo $?
1

$ var=$(command info put)
info: No menu item 'put' in node '(dir)Top'
$ echo $?
0

$ var=$(command info put); echo $?
info: No menu item 'put' in node '(dir)Top'
0
```

It's also the same behavior when `

So why does that general solution not work in this case?
And how to change/adapt the solution to make it work properly?

### My environment/system

I'm working on Windows 10 with WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS:

```sh
$ tmux -V
tmux 3.0a

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ info --version
info (GNU texinfo) 6.7
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using bash? I can't reproduce that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/exit-code-of-variable-assignment-to-command-substitution-in-bash

Comment: Your expected behavior is required by POSIX, so it should work in any compatible shell.

Comment: What do you see if you use `var=$(false); echo $?`?

Comment: This appears to be specific to the `info` command (maybe just some versions of it?). In my quick tests it exits with a success status (despite actually failing) if its stdout is not a tty.

Comment: @Barmar I added some information about my environment

Comment: @GordonDavisson so this means there is a bug in `info` and the "solution" code is actually correct?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I have the same output. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying out this solution with command info put the if clause is executed even if the actual command fails, but I can't explain myself why?

Indeed, `info` exits with `0`, when output is not a terminal and there's an error.

```
// texinfo/info.c
  if ((!isatty (fileno (stdout))) && (user_output_filename == NULL))
    {
      user_output_filename = xstrdup ("-");
   ...
    }
  ...
      // in called get_initial_file()
      asprintf (error, _("No menu item '%s' in node '%s'"),
        (*argv)[0], "(dir)Top");
  ...
  if (user_output_filename)
    {
      if (error)
        info_error ("%s", error);
      ...
      exit (0);                    // exits with 0!
    }
```

References: https://github.com/debian-tex/texinfo/blob/master/info/info.c#L848 , https://github.com/debian-tex/texinfo/blob/master/info/info.c#L277 , https://github.com/debian-tex/texinfo/blob/master/info/info.c#L1066 .

> why does that general solution not work in this case?

Because the behavior of the command changes when its output is redirected not to a terminal.

> how to change/adapt the solution to make it work properly?

You could simulate a tty - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157458/make-program-in-a-pipe-think-it-has-tty , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal .

You could grab `stderr` of the command and check if it's not-empty or match with some regex.

I think you could also contact texinfo developers and let them know that it's I think a bug and make a patch, so it would be like `exit(error ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS);`.

Comment: So it's a bug in `info`? Should we create a PR to fix that?

Comment: In my `bashrc` I have a function called `my_less` which checks if a command exited successfully and if so it pipes its output to `less` (basically the "solution" code from my question). So I should now change that function so that it simulate a tty every time and for every call, just because `info` does not work as expected?

Comment: For me, it looks like a bug. It is that `info -o /root/somefile get` exits with success, while the command failed. `I should now change...` I would handle only specifically `info` specially, workarounds, like `if [[ "$1" == "info" ]]; then handle info specially`, bugs happen. Then when bug is fixed, you would `if [[ "$1" == "info" ]] && info_version lower_then something; then handle info specially`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the exit status of the command, I ended up with saving the output and simply checking if there is any output that could be used for further processing (in my case piping into less):

```sh
my_less () {
  output=$("$@")
  if [[ ! -z "$output" ]]; then
    printf '%s' "$output" | less
  fi
}
```

Even with the bug in `info`, my function now works as the bug only affects the command's exit status. It's error messages are written to `stderr` as expected, so I'm using that behavior.