# eval variable assignment in a bash function causes variable to be local

Tags: bash, sh, ash

I was trying out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26827443/1193729) (the portion that is bash <= 4 compatible) when I noticed that bash behaved differently if the following line was in or out of a function. When in a function, the variables created by the `eval` were local variables, which is odd because there is no local keyword in the `eval` string.

```
eval "$({ berr=$({ bout=$("$@"); bret=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p bout bret >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)"

function captureStdOutRetCode () {
  eval "$({ berr=$({ bout=$("$@"); bret=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p bout bret >&2); declare -p berr; } 2>&1)"
}
echo "_${bout}_${berr}_${bret}_" # ____
```

My end goal is to port this to something that is compatible with `ash` and is callable as a function. My plan is to replace the `declare` bits with `echo "bout='$bout'"` since in my case I know the command's output is safe to `eval` without the escaping that `declare` provides (or would provide in `bash` at least).

Comment: It's not `eval`; `declare` creates a local variable unless you use the `-g` flag (introduced in `bash` 4.2).

Comment: Thanks, you should provide that as an answer so I can accept it.