# Capturing stdout into a variable

Tags: bash

This might be a naive question, but I'm really not sure how to do it. I submit a spark job and I get the following output.

Run job succeeded. Submission id: driver-20170824224209-0001

I want to programmatically query the status of this job. How can I use the output in the console to extract the id to a variable using a bash script.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean when you run a program, it outputs that string `Run job...` and you want to get the id from that string into a variable?

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you command is `cmd` and you want to store the output of the command in ( say ) a variable called `res`, one way in `bash` is to run the command in single quotes

```
res=`cmd`
```

or embed the command within `$()`

```
res=$(cmd)
```

[Capture both stdout and stderr in Bash](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806626/capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash&ved=2ahUKEwjGu762_MDeAhWGfCsKHWlLCsoQjjgwAHoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0KqqxT4sToE7j0b8qzXccH)

Comment: The characters in the first format are actually backticks ` rather than single quotes '