# bash: Run a command once and save stdout and stderr in their own variables

Tags: bash, variables, io-redirection, command-substitution

I need to ensure a command is outputting the correct text. I currently have:

```
command_stdout="$(mycommand --flag 2>/dev/null)"
command_stderr="$(mycommand --flag 2>&1 1>/dev/null)"
```

Instead of having to run the same command twice, is there any way I can run it once but still be able to save stdout and stderr's output to their appropriate variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806626/capture-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027679/capture-stdout-and-stderr-into-different-variables

Answer (score 4):

Redirect stderr to a file, then set the second variable to the file contents.

```
command_stdout="$(mycommand --flag 2>/tmp/stderr.$$)"
command_stderr="$(</tmp/stderr.$$)"
rm /tmp/stderr.$$
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works. Is there a way to do with without having to write files?

Comment: Can't think of any. You can only assign to one variable at a time.

Comment: If I knew a better way, don't you think I would have put that in the answer instead?

Comment: For symmetry, you could redirect *both* streams to files, then read them both into their respective variables :)

Comment: Is something like this possible? I can't get it to work, but I'm probably missing something: `command_stderr="$(command_stdout="$(mycommand --flag)" 2>&1)"`

Comment: No, because the `command_stdout` assignment is happening in a subshell, it won't be visible in the main shell.